# BQ PY Client Library :: Iterate large results thought pagination

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-bigquery

I'm learning [BQ PY Client Libraries], CLs[1](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html)

my query returns large results (>1m rows) and would like to paginate through the results (for ex. fetch 100K results a time, instead all 1M row sin one go!)

I checked [REST APIs doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) and it seems the parameter `maxResults` could be used to achieve that (setting it to desired # of rows in each page fetch?!)

It seems Client Library methods don't yet support this parameter ?

- I'm using `job.result()` method to fetch results (after query status changes to `DONE`) and the [GH code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/696b307594412102460d0ee66d601117118e5217/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py#L2478) doesn't mention any parameter to achieve that. Looking at HTTP request the CLs seem to make request with `?maxResults=0`
- I also tried `job.result().pages` (to get pages iterator) and iterate through pages.. but each page seems to have arbitrary number of rows (close to 55K) (how do CLs decide that?) Cannot seem to specify any parameter value to control # rows per page? It doesn't seem so..

**how can I iterate through pages using own custom maxResults value**

Comment: `maxResults` specifies the *maximum* number of rows per page, and BigQuery may not return that many, even if you were able to set it through the client. You cannot retrieve arbitrarily-large pages from BigQuery; you need to iterate over the pages.

Comment: Thanks Elliot! That’s exactly I wanna do. How can I use maxResults parameter using Client Library ? I don’t seem to locate a method that allows me to pagination through results using this parameter

Comment: You cannot use this parameter (and as I said, it would not give you the behavior that you want in any case). You need to iterate over the pages that the client returns.

Comment: I see... can I have control on number of rows in each page ? Or is that pre-determined any client library (on what basis or fixed rows per page)?

Comment: It's BigQuery itself that decides how many rows to include in each page based on the size of the days.

Comment: I'd also consider exporting these results to GCS in compressed format instead and them downloading it from there.